# PHP MySQL code not inserting data into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to process a form which will insert data into database, but it is inserting nothing in database. I am trying this for a couple of days, but got no solution. It is also not showing any error also.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $generic_drug_name = $_POST['generic_drug_name'];
  $brand_drug_name = $_POST['brand_drug_name'];
  $manufacturer_name = $_POST['manufacturer_name'];
  $type = $_POST['type'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
 }else{
  $generic_drug_name = '';
  $brand_drug_name = '';
  $manufacturer_name = '';
  $type = '';
  $price = '';
}
$errors = ''; 
$errors['generic_drug_nameErr'] = '';
$errors['brand_drug_nameErr'] = '';
$errors['manufacturer_nameErr'] = '';
$errors['typeErr'] = '';
$errors['priceErr'] = '';

?>
<body>
<header>
<?php echo navigation(); ?>
</header>
<section>       
<div id="envelope">

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

<?php       

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["generic_drug_name"])) {
           $errors['generic_drug_nameErr'] = "Name is required";

        }else{
           $generic_drug_name = test_input($_POST["generic_drug_name"]);
             // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$generic_drug_name)) {
               $errors['generic_drug_nameErr'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
             }
           }
        if (empty($_POST["brand_drug_name"])) {
           $errors['brand_drug_nameErr'] = "Name is required";

        }else{
           $brand_drug_name = test_input($_POST["brand_drug_name"]);
             // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$brand_drug_name)) {
               $errors['brand_drug_nameErr'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
             }
           }
        if (empty($_POST["manufacturer_name"])) {
           $errors['manufacturer_nameErr'] = "Name is required";

        }else{
           $manufacturer_name = test_input($_POST["manufacturer_name"]);
             // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$manufacturer_name)) {
               $errors['manufacturer_nameErr'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
             }
           }
        if (empty($_POST["type"])) {
             $errors['typeErr'] = "Type is required";
           } else {
             $type = test_input($_POST["type"]);
             // check if e-mail address is well-formed
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$type)) {
               $errors['typeErr'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
             }
           }
        if (empty($_POST["price"])) {
             $errors['priceErr'] = "";
           } else {
             $price = test_input($_POST["price"]);
             // check if e-mail address is well-formed
             if (!preg_match("/^[0-9\_]{1,4}/",$price)) {
               $errors['priceErr'] = "Invalid price format";
             }
           }                        
    }
?>
<center><h1>Add a new brand drug</h1></center><br>
<label>Generic Drug Name</label><span class="error">* </span><span class="text"><?php echo $errors['generic_drug_nameErr'];?></span>
<input type="text" name="generic_drug_name" placeholder="Enter Generic drug Names" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($generic_drug_name); ?>" width="100px;"/>
<label>Brand Drug Name</label><span class="error">* </span><span class="text"><?php echo $errors['brand_drug_nameErr'];?></span>
<input type="text" name="brand_drug_name" placeholder="Amlokind" autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($brand_drug_name); ?>" width="100px;">
<label>Manufacturer</label><span class="error">* </span><span class="text"><?php echo $errors['manufacturer_nameErr'];?></span>
<input type="text" name="manufacturer_name" placeholder="Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Pvt. Ltd." autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($manufacturer_name); ?>">
<label>Type</label><span class="error">* </span><span class="text"><?php echo $errors['typeErr'];?></span>
<input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Tablet" autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($type); ?>">       
<label>Price</label><span class="error">* </span><span class="text"><?php echo $errors['priceErr'];?></span>
<input type="text" name="price" placeholder="10.45" autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($price); ?>" >
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Add" id="submit"/>

</form>
</div>
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 /*$generic_drug_name = $_POST['generic_drug_name'];
 $brand_drug_name = $_POST['brand_drug_name'];
 $manufacturer_name = $_POST['manufacturer_name'];
 $type = $_POST['type'];
 $price = $_POST['price'];*/
    if(empty($errors)){
        $safe_generic_drug_name = strtoupper($generic_drug_name);               
        $safe_brand_drug_name = strtoupper($brand_drug_name);
        $safe_manufacturer_name = ucwords($manufacturer_name);
        $safe_type = ucfirst($type);
        $safe_price = $price;

        $query = "INSERT INTO brand_generic.brand_drug (drug_id, brand_drug_name, manufacturer, type, price)   
                    SELECT id, '{$safe_brand_drug_name}','{$safe_manufacturer_name}', '{$safe_type}', {$safe_price}
                    FROM brand_generic.generic_drug 
                    WHERE generic_drug_name = '{$safe_generic_drug_name}';";
                //INSERT INTO brand_generic.brand_drug (drug_id, brand_drug_name, manufacturer, type, price) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM brand_generic.generic_drug WHERE generic_drug_name = 'AMLODIPINE'), 'ZODIPINE', 'Zorex Pharma Pvt  Ltd', 'Tablet', 10);
        if(!$query){ 
            die(mysqli_error());
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        var_dump($result);

        if($result){
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Successfully subject created";
            //redirect_to("manage_content.php");
        echo $_SESSION["message"];
        }else{
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Sorry, subject couldn't be created";
            //redirect_to("new_subject.php");
        echo $_SESSION["message"];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

This code is also not showing any error....so that's why I can't tell you what's wrong here.......but when I put

```
if(!empty($errors)){
```

instead of

```
if(empty($errors)){
```

This works - it should not work, right? Because it will take any data and insert it into database.

Comment: Is your error reporting on? `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of the page.

Comment: You aren't displaying the $errors array if there is errors..

Comment: So i would say there is errors, but they aren't being echo'd because you haven't told it to echo them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you always fill your `$errors` array with (empty) strings. Try this:

```
$errors = array();
```

Instead of this:

```
$errors = ''; 
$errors['generic_drug_nameErr'] = '';
$errors['brand_drug_nameErr'] = '';
$errors['manufacturer_nameErr'] = '';
$errors['typeErr'] = '';
$errors['priceErr'] = '';
```

Comment: I think you mean in the form don't you? That's because it isn't defined. You should try: `<?= (isset($errors['generic_drug_nameErr']) ? $errors['generic_drug_nameErr'] : '') ?>` instead of `<?php echo $errors['generic_drug_nameErr'];?>` that means it only tries to reach it if it is set (isset) else he will display '' (nothing).